# global variables not parsing as parameters

Tags: expressionengine

I am having troubles with global variables not parsing when passed as parameters.

```
{exp:channel:entries    
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    dynamic="no"
    entry_id="{structure:child_ids_for:21}"
}
```

(0.012500 / 3.36MB) Tag: {exp:channel:entries disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no" entry_id="{structure:child_ids_for:21}" }

The same result is produced with and without parse="inward"

However this works fine and grabs the data I need

```
{exp:channel:entries    
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    dynamic="no"
    entry_id="{exp:query sql='SELECT exp_structure.entry_id, 
            exp_structure.parent_id, 
            exp_structure.lft
            FROM exp_structure
            WHERE parent_id = 21
            ORDER BY exp_structure.lft ASC'}{entry_id}|{/exp:query}"
    parse="inward"
}
```

But, then if I add in a global variable author_id="{logged_in_member_id}" it fails to work, if I hard code that value as 1 then it functions.

Any thoughts as to what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for Structure's global variables, but `{logged_in_member_id}` is a *late-parsed global variable*, meaning you can't use it in a module tag parameter. I can only only assume that the same goes for the Structure variables.

You *can* use the `CURRENT_USER` constant in the `author_id` parameter though ([docs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#author-id)).

Unfortunately, the solution for your `{structure:child_ids_for:21}` issue is to pass that as an [embed variable](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding.html#embed-variables-for-the-embedded-template), and put your Channel Entries loop in an embed. (I say unfortunately because embeds do incur some overhead.)

One note: `parse="inward"` has no effect on module tag pairs - they *always* parse inward. It only affects plugin tag pairs.

Comment: Thanks Derek, trying to avoid embeds but that appears to the be the solution here. Thank you for your input, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the overhead of embeds by using [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev) for this sort of thing. It has the insanely useful ability to let you explicitly state your preferred parse order for different chunks of code. In this case the first thing you'd do is store the two variables via `{exp:stash:set}`, then you can retrieve them in the second chunk of code via `{exp:stash:get}`. The magic bit is the parse priority tag; because the first item has a priority of 10 it will be executed first, which ensures the vars are available for use as channel entries parameters in the second `{exp:stash:parse}` tag.

```
{exp:stash:parse priority="10" process="end"}
    {exp:stash:set}
        {stash:structure_ids}{structure:sibling_ids}{/stash:structure_ids}
        {stash:logged_in_member}{logged_in_member_id}{/stash:logged_in_member}
    {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:stash:parse}

{exp:stash:parse priority="20" process="end"}
    {exp:channel:entries
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
        dynamic="no"
        entry_id="{exp:stash:get name='structure_ids'}"
        author_id="{exp:stash:get name='logged_in_member'}"
        parse="inward"
    }
    ...
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```